# Get checked values in other view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have list of checkbox with button submit , and I when i click on submit, I have to get all checked values in other view table. I find a lot of answers, but they all propose to get values in the same view,but I need to get values in other view(ajoutFactAdmin2), how can I do that please. this is the code:

ajoutFactAdmin2.html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in namesF3">

          <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" name="" ng-modal="x.selected" ng-checked="exist(x)" ng-click="toggleSelection(x)" ng-true-value="'{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}'" ng-false-value="''" id="'{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}'"></div>
          <div class="col" >{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}</div>   
          <div class="col" width="20%">{{x.StatutColis}}  </div>
          <div class="col" width="20%">{{x.VilleDestColis}}</div> 

</div>

<div class="selectedcontent">
            <h3> Selected Names </h3>
            <p ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected"> {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}} </p>
</div>
          <a class="button button-info"   ng-click="toggleSelection(x)"  href="#/ajoutFactAdmin2" style="background-color:#1627C0;float: right;">Ajouter</a>
```

app.js :

```
 $scope.selected = [];
           $scope.namesF3 = [];
          $scope.exist = function(item){
            return $scope.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
          }

          $scope.toggleSelection = function(item){
             var x = [];
            var idx = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);
            if(idx > -1){
                 $scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
            }
             else{
                 $scope.selected.push(item);
             }

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like when user click submit button you need to call one function on controller and stored all value checked value in local storage and redirect to next page and next controller you have to get local storage value and display in view page.

or

You can do like from controller function you have to pass array as string and in next controller get state param value and use json.parse for convert string to object and display in html

Comment: thank you for your answer, sorry to say that I am beginner with angular, Can you explain more how can I do that please.